# How to check the Language in which Exe is made

Tags: compiler-construction, assemblies, exe, machine-code

We were studying about compilers at college so this raised me curiosity that when we use the compilers and they form assemblies so is there any way you could know that ,if you are given any exe, which compiler was used to build it?or atleast which language was this exe made with c++,c# or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways of doing this, but I don't think you can guarantee a valid result depending on what steps people go through to hide it.

Check out [PEiD](http://www.peid.info/), it can to do this automatically (along with detecting packers, etc).